# Create a custom operator for renaming input socket in compositor

Tags: python, node-editor, compositing-nodes, operator

i'm working on a little script to get the right file output name automatically in the compositor, so far so good, my little script works, but i can't turn it into a custom operator to make it executable from a ui panel.
Here's what i've got so far (thanks to several people in here :) )

```
import bpy
import os

# Get absolute render path:
filepath = bpy.context.scene.render.filepath
absolutepath = bpy.path.abspath(filepath)

# Split it
path = os.path.normpath(absolutepath)
parts = path.split(os.sep)

parentpath = os.sep.join(parts[:-2])

# Add rename operator
def rename (context):
    # set the path for all file output nodes:
    for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
        for node in scene.node_tree.nodes:


            if node.type == 'OUTPUT_FILE':
                #gets the link from the input
                link0 = node.inputs[0].links[0]


                #returns the name of the socket the link is from
                socket_name = link0.from_socket.name 

                node.base_path = parentpath
                node.label = socket_name
                node.file_slots[0].path = "\_" + "nom" + "_" + socket_name + "\_" + "nom" + "_" +  socket_name + "_"

    class RenameFO(bpy.types.Operator):
        """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "Rename.F_O"
    bl_label = "Rename File Outputs"

    def execute(self, context):
            rename(context)
            return {'FINISHED'}


# Create custom panel    
class FOM(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "File Output Manager"
    bl_idname = "File_output_manager"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "render"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("Rename.F_O" , text = "Rename")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(RenameFO)
    bpy.utils.register_class(FOM)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(RenameFO)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(FOM)



    register()
```

Does someone know what i'm doing wrong ? 
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you haven't worked it out by now:

```
import bpy
import os
filepath=bpy.context.scene.render.filepath#Get absolute render path
absolutepath=bpy.path.abspath(filepath)
path=os.path.normpath(absolutepath)#Split it
parts=path.split(os.sep)
parentpath=os.sep.join(parts[:-2])
def rename(context):#Set the path for all file output nodes
    for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
        if scene.node_tree:
            for node in scene.node_tree.nodes:
                if node.type=='OUTPUT_FILE':
                    link0=node.inputs[0].links[0]#Gets the link from the input
                    socket_name=link0.from_socket.name#Returns the name of the socket the link is from
                    node.base_path=parentpath
                    node.label=socket_name
                    node.file_slots[0].path="\_"+"nom"+"_"+socket_name+"\_"+"nom"+"_"+socket_name+"_"
class FILE_OT_rename_file_outputs(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Renames file outputs"""
    bl_idname="render.rename_file_outputs"
    bl_label="Rename File Outputs"
    def execute(self,context):
        rename(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}
class FILE_PT_rename_file_outputs(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label="File Output Manager"
    bl_space_type='PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type='WINDOW'
    bl_context="render"
    def draw(self,context):
        layout=self.layout
        row=layout.row()
        row.operator("render.rename_file_outputs",text="Rename")
classes=[FILE_OT_rename_file_outputs,FILE_PT_rename_file_outputs]
def register():
    for c in classes:bpy.utils.register_class(c)
def unregister():
    for c in classes:bpy.utils.unregister_class(c)
if __name__=="__main__":register()
```

Comment: hey man thank you ! i already found a similar solution over the web , but thanks for the answer :)